# Add existing project in a solution - cause reference namespace error

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, nuget

I just create a new project. And then add an existing project in that new project.
The problem is after finish to add that existing project. All the reference are missing error.

*Just to know. The existing project i added, was already added in another project and use the* "**restore nuget package**"

The following error appear :

```
"Some NuGet packages are missing from this solution. Click to restore from your online package sources"
```

But after try to restore the package i get the new following message :

```
"All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore."
```

[image]

Both use the same Framework version - 4.5.2
[image]

Comment: Did you try just rebuild a solution after adding a project and not to use "package restore" command? VS should do it automatically.

Comment: Right click one of the references and check the path. Is the dll in that path? http://pumpingco.de/my-visual-studio-solution-wont-build-although-it-should-what-can-i-do/

Comment: @IlyaChumakov , yes thisis the first things i tried. But after that , they ask me to "turn on the restore of NuGet package" , if i tried. it's doesn't work.

Comment: @SteveGreene . if i check the properties is write nothing in the "path" properties... of each dll it's weird

Comment: Do you have a packages folder? I would clean the solution, exit VS and delete the .suo file for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the solution. It's was because i open the solution with VS 2015 but the project i added was created with Visual Studio 2013 , i think nuget  package have some bug for restore package from VS 2013 to VS 2015

1. First open my solution with (Visual Studio 2013),software that I created the referenced project
2. Click on the option "Restore the nuget package" from the solution
3. Re-open the solution on Visual Studio 2015 and then enjoy ^^